# Setting up a new guest virtual network adapter in C#?

Tags: .net, vmware

In PowerCLI you'd basically do

```
$vm | New-NetworkAdapter -Portgroup $name -Type Vmxnet3 -StartConnected
```

and be done.

However, I'm trying to accomplish this in .Net.  I'm able to connect to vsphere and query grab the VirtualMachine.  I'm even able to query to see if the adapter exists using

```
vm.Guest.Net.NotEmpty() && vm.Guest.Net.Where(nicInfo => nicInfo.Network == portgroupName).NotEmpty();
```

I'm just not sure how to actually add the adapter once I've identified that it doesn't exist.

Any help?  A link to an example would be nice, I've googled all over the place and I can't see to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the standard vSphere SDK or some kind of wrapper on top of it? I haven't seen the `vm.Guest.Net` syntax in the vSphere SDK.

Assuming that you're using the web services SDK, you can add a NIC by way of the `ReconfigVM_Task` API call (http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html?path=7_1_0_2_5_16_25#reconfigure). At a high level, you will need to create a `VirtualMachineConfigSpec` with a `deviceChange` field that contains the NIC you want to create. Since your PowerShell example mentioned VmxNet3, you'll want a device of type `VirtualVmxnet3` whose `backing` field is of type `VirtualEthernetCardDistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo` (if you're connecting to a VDS) or `VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo` (if you're connecting to a VSS).

Once you pass that config spec to the `ReconfigVM_Task` API, it should update the VM and add the NIC for you.